# During Open(), SqlConnection.ServerVersion throws System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: sqlconnection

When running a webservice, web page that knows how to respond.  The service connects to a dbase.  During the sqlconnection.open call, ASP .NET code throws the following exception:

sqlConnection.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

NOTE:  I'm running this on my dev machine.  When it runs on live web server, all is well.  It is unique to my system.

I'm I missing a configuration setting with Sql Server 2008?

NOTE:  recently upgraded from Sql Server 2005 to 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could possibly be caused by a difference in your web.config between the live server and your dev machine.  Have you checked that the connection string is properly specified?

Comment: The connection string is same for both environments, same copy of web.config

Comment: I'm glad you found your problem with the connection string.  If my reply was helpful, please consider marking it as the answer.  (I'm trying to get to however many reputation points I need to post comments on other people's answers.)

Answer (score 1):

Found problem.  There was a space in the front of the connection string.